# Reverting(?) commit and pull request

Tags: git, github, conflict

So I've been working on this implementation of Firebase for a while, trying to figure out Kotlin and ended up spending more time than probably suggested for a single commit. When all was set I went a head and committed the changes including making a pull request to look over eventual conflicts and ended up having unsolvable(?) conflicts in files that (obviously) should have been in GitIgnore; [As this shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKmrt.png)

How do I revert the commit including the pull request so I don't end up deleting any of my work?

Really appreciative for any help I can get!

Comment: GitHub tells you what to do: https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-merge-conflicts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following steps can help you:

1. `git log` by this command you can see the git log.
2. `git checkout <commit hash code>` by this one you can back to the
   stable version you had.

Also simply you can write `git revert <commit hash code>` just to revert the commit that makes the problem.